# angular2 APP_INITIALIZER synchronously

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I need to make two HTTP call one after another before angular initialize. Is there any way to initialize angular 2 synchronously?

**Please do not say our app should work asynchronously.** 
I am working on generic build using "angular-cli" . First i need to fetch the environment which is set in a json file and on the basis of that environment i need to load configuration. So i need two HTTP calls.

```
{ 
provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
   useFactory: (config: AppConfig) => () => config.load(),
   deps: [AppConfig], multi: true
}
```

Inside load() i have two http call one inside other but before two call get completed angular is initialized.

Comment: would https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9047#issuecomment-255597990 work ? careful: APP_INITIALIZER is experimental: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/APP_INITIALIZER-let.html

Comment: @Rohit can you check my answer?

Answer (score 3):

You're on a correct way.
You can make both http calls into config.load() function.

```
 public load() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.http.get('first.json').map( res => res.json() ).catch((error: any):any => {

            console.error('Error at first call');

            resolve(error);
            return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
        }).subscribe( (firstResponse) => {

            let request = this.http.get('second.json');

            request
                .map( res => res.json() )
                .catch((error: any) => {
                    console.error('Error at second call');
                    resolve(error);
                    return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
                })
                .subscribe((secondResponse) => {

                    //Here i have both
                    firstResponse, secondResponse

                    resolve(true);
                });

        });

    });
}
```

Consider the fact that functions and lambdas are not supported to `useFactory` anymore, so you have to rewrite it little bit. Also make sure that you provide your AppConfig

```
function initialConfigLoad(config: AppConfig) {
    return () => config.load();
};

providers: [
    ...
    AppConfig, // <- Provide AppConfig
    {
        provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
        useFactory: initialConfigLoad,
        deps: [AppConfig],
        multi: true
    }
]
```

Comment: Note that the most important part of this piece of code is the call to `resolve(true);` in the Promise. It signals to Angular that it can continue with the app initialization.